# preg_replace script, link tag not working

Tags: php, seo, html-parsing

I used the following code to remove script, link tags from my string,

```
$contents='<script>inside tag</script>hfgkdhgjh<script>inside 2</script>';
$ss=preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $contents);
echo htmlspecialchars($ss);
```

it works fine. But can I use anything that similar to html parsing rather than preg_match for this?

Comment: Have you made sure you're getting something back from your call?

Comment: strip_tags might help http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php ... look at user contributed scripts at the bottom of the page

Comment: @jpofit: yes, it returns the site contents, after stripping the contents and tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are few things you can do

1. `htmlspecialchars()` can prove those tags useless
2. `striptags()` removes all HTML tags

But the technique you are using is the correct one. However here is a improved version for that

```
echo preg_replace('/<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/is', "", $contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

[HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) is always a good choice. [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) has also come in handy a few times.

If you are sanitizing content, it's very easy to make mistakes with regular expressions... read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). It just depends what you're trying to achieve.